# Simplify redundant std::array initialization when class has no constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a much more complex version of the following code:

```
#include <array>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Dummy
{
    public:
        Dummy(const double a, const double f)
        {
            //Some complex calculations
        }
};

constexpr double values[] { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 };
constexpr auto N = sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0]);
static const array<Dummy, N> dummies {Dummy(10 * values[0], M_PI * 0),
                                      Dummy(10 * values[1], M_PI * 1),
                                      Dummy(10 * values[2], M_PI * 2),
                                      Dummy(10 * values[3], M_PI * 3)};

int main()
{
    //Complex use of dummies
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to simplify the initialization of the `dummies` array as it is highly redundant. However, I am bound to C++11 and I cannot change the `Dummy` class to have a `constexpr` constructor (which would greatly simplify my situation).

I have looked at variadic templates, but can't seem to get around the fact that `Dummy`'s constructor is not `constexpr`:

```
template<size_t... Is>
struct _Helper
{
    static constexpr array<Dummy, N> dummies {Dummy(10 * values[Is], M_PI * Is)...}; //Fails to compile because Dummy's constructor is not constexpr
};

static const array<Dummy, N> dummies { _Helper<0, 1, 2, 3>::dummies };
```

Are there any other ways to simplify the initialization of the array? `values` could be redeclared as literally anything else that can be converted back to `double[]` at runtime.

Comment: Does `Dummy` have a default constructor?

Comment: @Nelfeal: No, it doesn't, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you also have 4 dummies in the real code?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I have several arrays like this, some of which have more than 4 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can create a make function as follows

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
std::array<Dummy, sizeof...(Is)> makeDummArr (double const * vals)
 { return { { Dummy(10 * vals[Is], M_PI * Is)... } }; } }
```

and use it to initialize

```
static const std::array<Dummy, N> dummies = makeDummArr<0, 1, 2, 3>(values);
```

It's a pity you're bound to C++11: if your `Is...` list is sequential (starting from zero) and a long list, if you could use C++14... so `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence`...

I mean

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
std::array<Dummy, sizeof...(Is)> makeDummArr
   (double const * vals, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return { { Dummy(10 * vals[Is], M_PI * Is)... } }; }


static const std::array<Dummy, N> dummies
   = makeDummArr(values, std::make_index_sequence<4U>{});
```

(or you can follows the HolyBlackCat's suggestion and create, in C++11, a substitute for `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`)

Comment: I like this solution. I aim for C++14 support in the long term. To make sure of the correct array dimensions, I modified your `vals` parameter like this: `const double (&vals)[sizeof...(Is)]`

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger - works, and improve the dimension check and safety, but loose in flexibility (you can't initialize `dummies` with a pointer to `double` but only a C-style `double` array). See you what is better, in your project.

Answer (score 2):

The code below is similar to what @max66 suggested,
but doesn't require you to type `0, 1, ..., N-1` manually.

```
template <int ...I> struct int_seq // A rip-off of C++14 std::index_sequence.
{
    template <int X> using push_back = int_seq<I..., X>;
};
template <int N> struct make_int_seq_impl
{
    using type = typename make_int_seq_impl<N-1>::type::template push_back<N-1>;
};
template <> struct make_int_seq_impl<0>
{
    using type = int_seq<>;
};
template <int N> using make_int_seq = typename make_int_seq_impl<N>::type;

template <int ...I> array<Dummy, N> make_dummies(int_seq<I...>)
{
    return {Dummy(10 * values[I], M_PI * I)...};
}

static const array<Dummy, N> dummies = make_dummies(make_int_seq<N>{});
```